# Setting NameIdFormat for SAML

Tags: spring-saml

I have the following webSsoProfileOptions:

`@Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions options = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        options.setNameID(NameIDType.TRANSIENT);
        return options;
    }`

But the MetadataGenerator produces the following name-id-formats:

`<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>`

How to change the generator that only `<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>` is produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be set to MetadataGenerator.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-sp-generation